# html - form table - invalid markup

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I understand it is incorrect to have a form inside a table row.  There does seem to be a practical reason for doing this though.

I would like to be able to edit each row individually (ajax and such), so it makes sense that each for is its own form.

Below is functionally how I need the table and form to be laid out, but the markup isn't valid. And furthermore, haml/erb actually won't process the markup like this (the form is opened and closed within the first cell).

I could use display: table-cell and such, but I think the data I'm displaying does belong in a table, semantically.

How can I accomplish the same function with proper markup?

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th> 
    <th>email</th>
    <th>phone</th>
    <th>address</th> 
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <%= form_for person do |f| %>
      <td><%= id %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :name%></td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th> 
    <th>email</th>
    <th>phone</th>
    <th>address</th> 
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= form_for person do |f| %>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><%= id %></td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :name%></td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That'll work.  The data doesn't really require a nested table though, so it still seems like a layout hack.  And it could take more css to make sure the THs are the same width as their respective TD.

Comment: If that's your scenario then I think you either need to revert to spans/divs for the nested tds or use one form and parse the data server side to know which row was submitted.